# I get the error "free(): double free detected in tcache 2" while reading a file

Tags: c++, oop, runtime-error

When I try to compile my code in any IDE different than Visual Studio Code, I get the following error right after reading the file:

> free(): double free detected in tcache 2.

When I delete the destructor, the program runs well, but the 'sort' function outputs all the lines as [(0,0),(0,0)]. I don't know why this happens. As mentioned, in Visual Studio Code, the program runs well from the beginning. Is there any solution to this problem? Am I missing anything?

Here are my codes and the files I am using:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <iomanip>

#include "Line.hpp"
#include "Point.hpp"

using namespace std;

void inputLines(string filename, vector <Line>& Lines){

    ifstream inFS;

    inFS.open(filename);

    // checking if opened

    if (!inFS.is_open()){
        cout << "Couldn't open the input file" << endl << endl;
        return;
    }

    //lines:
    char letter1, letter2, letter3, letter4, letter5, letter6, d1;
    inFS >> letter1 >> letter2 >> letter3 >> letter4 >> letter5 >> letter6>> d1;

    //{[line1:[102.0,0.9],[97.0,1.0]],
    char d2, letterl, letteri, lettern, lettere, letter_1, d3, d4,d5 ,d6 ,d7 ,d8 ,d9 ,d10 ,d11 ,d12;
    double linep1x, linep1y, linep2x, linep2y;


    while (!inFS.eof()){

    inFS >> d2 >> letterl >> letteri >> lettern >> lettere >> letter_1 >> d3 >> d4
         >> linep1x >> d5 >> linep1y >> d6 >> d7 >> d8 >> linep2x >> d9 >> linep2y >> d10 >> d11 >> d12;


    if(!inFS.fail() && d2 == '[' && letterl == 'l' &&  letteri == 'i' &&  lettern == 'n' &&  lettere == 'e' &&  d3 == ':' &&  d4 == '[' &&  d5 == ','
                    && d6 == ']' &&  d7 == ',' &&  d8 == '[' &&  d9 == ',' &&  d10== ']' &&  d11 == ']' ){

                    Lines.push_back(Line(linep1x,linep1y,linep2x,linep2y));
            }
        }

        inFS.close();
    }

bool parallel(Line& line1, Line& line2){

double slope1 = line1.getSlope();
double slope2 = line2.getSlope();

if(slope1 == slope2){

    return true;
}

return false;

}


int main (){


cout <<"\n-----------------------------------------------\n"<< "           Starting unit testing ... " << "\n-----------------------------------------------\n\n";

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


cout << "           ---------- | Testing setters and getters functions: | ----------\n\n";

Line l1_setGet;

cout << "We want to set a line with the coordinates (1,1)(2,2) and set the slope as 1.0 and the length as 1.41 \n\n";

Point p1_setGet(1,1);
Point p2_setGet(2,2);

l1_setGet.setPoint_1(p1_setGet);
l1_setGet.setPoint_2(p2_setGet);

l1_setGet.setSlope(1);
l1_setGet.setLength(1.41);

assert(l1_setGet.getLength() == 1.41);
assert(l1_setGet.getSlope() == 1);

cout << "All test passed...\n\n";

cout << "Line: " ; l1_setGet.print() ; cout << "\nSlope: " << l1_setGet.getSlope() << "\nLength: " << l1_setGet.getLength() <<"\n\n";

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


cout << "         ---------- | Testing null constructors and assigning constructor: | ----------\n\n";

Point p1_constructor(-32.4,22.4);
Point p2_constructor(44.2,-31.9);


Line l1_constructor;
Line l2_constructor(p1_constructor, p2_constructor);


cout << "We want the first line to be initialized by the null constructor and the second line to be set by the other constructor \n\n";

cout << "Line 1: \n         ";
l1_constructor.print(); cout << "\n\n";

cout << "Line 2: [initialized with (-32.4,22.4) and (44.2, -31.9)]  \n         ";
l2_constructor.print(); cout << "\n\n";

cout << "Let's also test how the constructor calculates the length and the slope. For the second line the slope would be (-0.7) and the length would be (93.9):\n\n";

cout << "Slope: " << l2_constructor.getSlope() << "\n";
cout << "Length: " << l2_constructor.getLength() << "\n\n";

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


cout << "         ---------- | Testing copy constructor and copy assignment operator: | ----------\n\n";

Point p1_copy(27.2,-29.3);
Point p2_copy(45.2, 11.9);

cout << "These are our test cases: \n\n";

Line l1_copy(p1_copy, p2_copy);
Line l3_copy;

cout << "         Line 1: "; l1_copy.print();  cout << "\n";
cout << "         Line 3: "; l3_copy.print();  cout << "\n\n";

cout << "Let's create and initialize the second line with the first line to test the copy constructor:\n\n";

Line l2_copy(l1_copy);

cout << "         Line 2: ";  l2_copy.print() ; cout << "\n\n";

cout << "Let's now use the assignment operator (=) to assign the second line to the third line:\n\n";

l3_copy = l2_copy;

cout << "         Line 3: ";  l3_copy.print() ; cout << "\n\n";

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

cout << "         ---------- | Testing the parallel function: | ----------\n\n";

Point p1_para(2.0, 46.4);
Point p2_para(4.0, 88.8);

Point p3_para(2.0, 52.4);
Point p4_para(4.0, 94.8);

Point p5_para(2.0, -32.4);
Point p6_para(4.0, -74.8);

cout << "These are our test cases: \n\n";

Line l1_para(p1_para,p2_para);
Line l2_para(p3_para,p4_para);
Line l3_para(p5_para,p6_para);


cout << "         Line 1'slope: " << l1_para.getSlope();  cout << "\n";
cout << "         Line 2'slope: " << l2_para.getSlope();  cout << "\n";
cout << "         Line 3'slope: " << l3_para.getSlope();  cout << "\n\n";

cout << "Two lines are parallel when they have the same slope. Let's test the parallel function:\n\n";

cout << "Let's see if Line 1 and Line 2 are parallel: \n\n";

parallel(l1_para,l2_para) == 1 ? cout << "They are parallel\n\n" : cout << "They are not parallel\n\n";
assert(parallel(l1_para,l2_para) == 1);

cout << "Let's see if Line 1 and Line 3 are parallel: \n\n";

parallel(l1_para,l3_para) == 1 ? cout << "They are parallel\n\n" : cout << "They are not parallel\n\n";
assert(parallel(l1_para,l3_para) == 0);

cout << "All tests passed...\n\n";

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

cout << "         ---------- | Testing the overloaded operators (< > ==): | ----------\n\n";

Point p1_oper(2, 2);
Point p2_oper(4, 4);

Point p3_oper(2, 2);
Point p4_oper(5, 5);

Point p5_oper(2, 2);
Point p6_oper(5, 5);

Point p7_oper(2, 2);
Point p8_oper(6, 6);



cout << "These are our test cases: \n\n";

Line l1_oper(p1_oper,p2_oper);
Line l2_oper(p3_oper,p4_oper);
Line l3_oper(p5_oper,p6_oper);
Line l4_oper(p7_oper,p8_oper);

cout << "         Line 1: " ; l1_oper.print();  cout << "     Length;  " << l1_oper.getLength() <<"\n";
cout << "         Line 2: " ; l2_oper.print();  cout << "     Length;  " << l2_oper.getLength() <<"\n";
cout << "         Line 3: " ; l3_oper.print();  cout << "     Length;  " << l3_oper.getLength() <<"\n";
cout << "         Line 4: " ; l4_oper.print();  cout << "     Length;  " << l4_oper.getLength() <<"\n\n";

cout << "       Let's test (<): \n\n";


cout << "(Line 1 < Line 2): ";
l1_oper < l2_oper == true ? cout << "True\n\n" : cout << "False\n\n";
assert( l1_oper < l2_oper == true );

cout << "(Line 2 < Line 1): ";
l2_oper < l1_oper == true ? cout << "True\n\n" : cout << "False\n\n";
assert( l2_oper < l1_oper == false );

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


cout << "       Let's test (>): \n\n";


cout << "(Line 2 > Line 3): ";
l2_oper > l3_oper == true ? cout << "True\n\n" : cout << "False\n\n";
assert( l2_oper > l3_oper == false  );

cout << "(Line 4 > Line 1): ";
l4_oper > l1_oper == true ? cout << "True\n\n" : cout << "False\n\n";
assert( l4_oper > l1_oper == true );

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

cout << "       Let's test (==): \n\n";


cout << "(Line 2 == Line 3): ";
l2_oper == l3_oper == true ? cout << "True\n\n" : cout << "False\n\n";
assert( l2_oper == l3_oper == true  );

cout << "(Line 1 == Line 4): ";
l1_oper == l4_oper == true ? cout << "True\n\n" : cout << "False\n\n";
assert( l1_oper == l4_oper == false  );
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

cout << "All tests passed...\n\n";

cout << "         ---------- | Testing the file reader function: | ----------\n\n"; //--------------------------------------------------------------------


vector <Line> Lines;
string filename = "lines.txt";

cout << "Reading file...\n\n";

inputLines(filename, Lines);

cout << "Outputting extracted coordinates out of the file: \n\n";

for (int i = 0 ; i < Lines.size() ; i++){

Lines.at(i).print();

cout << endl;

}

cout << endl;

cout << "         ---------- | Testing the sort function: | ----------\n\n"; //--------------------------------------------------------------------

Lines.clear();

string filename_2 = "lines_2.txt";

cout << "Reading file with non-sorted values...\n\n";

inputLines(filename_2, Lines);

cout << "Outputting extracted coordinates out of the file: \n\n";

for (int i = 0 ; i < Lines.size() ; i++){

Lines.at(i).print();

cout << endl;

}

cout << endl;

cout << "Sorting... \n\n";

sort(Lines.begin(), Lines.end());

cout << "Outputting sorted values: \n\n";

for (int i = 0 ; i < Lines.size() ; i++){

Lines.at(i).print();

cout << endl;

}

cout << endl;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Line l1_cout(1,2,3,4);

cout << "Overloading \"cout\" to print an object (in this case, a line with the coordinates (1,2),(3,4): \n\n";

cout << l1_cout << endl;

cout << endl;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


cout << "         ---------- | Testing the insertion operator (>> cin): | ----------\n\n";

Line l1_cin;

cout << "Enter a line in the format [(x1,y1),(x2,y2)] " << endl << endl;
cin >> l1_cin;

cout << "\nYou entered: " << endl << endl;
cout << "------- ";
l1_cin.print();
cout << " -------\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

**Line.hpp**

```
#include <cmath>
#include "Point.hpp"
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

#ifndef LINE_H
#define LINE_H

class Line{

    private:

    Point* p1;
    Point* p2;

    double slope;
    double length;

    public:

    Line(); //null constructor
    Line(Point p1, Point p2);
    Line(double linep1x, double linep1y, double linep2x,  double linep2y);


// !accessors and mutators


//---------------------------------------//
    void setPoint_1 (double x, double y){
        p1->setX(x);
        p1->setY(y);
        
        calculateLength();
        calculateSlope();
    }

    void setPoint_1 (Point p){
        *p1=p;

        calculateLength();
        calculateSlope();
    }

    Point getPoint_1() const{
        return *p1;
    }

//---------------------------------------//

    void setPoint_2 (double x, double y){
        p2->setX(x);
        p2->setY(y);

        calculateLength();
        calculateSlope();

    }

    void setPoint_2 (Point p){
        *p2=p;
        
        calculateLength();
        calculateSlope();
    }

    Point getPoint_2() const{
        return *p2;
    }
//---------------------------------------//

    void setSlope(double s){
        this->slope = s;
    }

    void calculateSlope(){

    slope = ( (p2->getY()) - (p1->getY()) ) / ((p2->getX()) - (p1->getX()) );

    }

    double getSlope() const{
        return this->slope;
    }
//---------------------------------------//

    void setLength(double l){
        this->length = l;
    }

    void calculateLength(){

    length = sqrt( (pow( ( (p2->getX()) - (p1->getX()) ) , 2) ) + (pow(( (p2->getY()) - (p1->getY())), 2 ) ) );

    }

    double getLength() const{
        return this->length;
    }
//---------------------------------------//

//!print

void print() const;

//!destructor

~Line();

//!copy constructor
Line(const Line& l);

//!assignment
Line& operator=(const Line& line);

//! overloading operators

bool operator==(const Line& line);
bool operator<(const Line& line);
bool operator>(const Line& line);

friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Line& L);
friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Line& L);

};

#endif

Line::Line(){ //*null constructor

slope = 0;
length= 0;

p1 = new Point();
p2 = new Point();

}


Line::Line(double linep1x, double linep1y, double linep2x,  double linep2y){


p1 = new Point ;
p2 = new Point ;

p1->setX(linep1x);
p1->setY(linep1y);

p2->setX(linep2x);
p2->setY(linep2y);

//The distance between two points is given by d(P, Q) = √(x2 − x1)² + (y2 − y1)²

calculateLength();

//The slope of a line, given two points, is defined as  m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)

calculateSlope();

}

Line::Line(Point point1, Point point2){ //*overload constructor to calculate length and slope

double x1 = point1.getX();
double y1 = point1.getY();

double x2 = point2.getX();
double y2 = point2.getY();

p1 = new Point(x1,y1);
p2 = new Point(x2,y2);

//The distance between two points is given by d(P, Q) = √(x2 − x1)² + (y2 − y1)²

calculateLength();

//The slope of a line, given two points, is defined as  m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)

calculateSlope();

}

//*destructor

Line::~Line(){

delete p1;
delete p2;

}

//*copy constructor

Line::Line(const Line& line){

this->p1 = new Point ;
this->p2 = new Point ;

this->p1 = line.p1;
this->p2 = line.p2;

length = line.length;
slope = line.slope;

}

//*assignment operator

Line& Line::operator=(const Line& line){

    if(this!=&line){

        delete this->p1;
        delete this->p2;

        this->p1 = new Point ;
        this->p2 = new Point ;

        this->p1 = line.p1;
        this->p2 = line.p2;

    }

return *this;
}

// * =

bool Line::operator==(const Line& line){

    if(this->length == line.length){

        return true;
    }


   return false;
}



//* < operator

bool Line::operator<(const Line& line){

    if(this->length < line.length){

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

//* > operator

bool Line::operator>(const Line& line){

    return (!(this->length < line.length) && !(this->length == line.length));
}


// * << operator (cout)

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Line& L){

out << "[(" << (L.p1->getX()) << ", " << (L.p1->getY()) <<"), (" << L.p2->getX() << ", " << (L.p2->getY()) <<")]";
    return out;
}

// * >> operator (cin)

istream& operator>>(istream& in, Line& L){

char d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8, d9;
double x1, y1, x2, y2;

        //[(x1,y1),(x2,y2)]
    in >> d1 >> d2 >> x1 >> d3 >> y1 >> d4 >> d5 >> d6 >> x2 >> d7 >> y2 >> d8 >> d9;


    if(!(d1 == '[' && d2 == '(' &&  d3 == ',' &&  d4 == ')' &&  d5 == ',' &&  d6 == '('  &&  d7 == ',' &&  d8 == ')' &&  d9 == ']' )){

                cout << "Invalid format" << endl;
            }
    else{

        L.setPoint_1(x1,y1);
        L.setPoint_2(x2, y2);
    }

return in;
}




//* print function

void Line::print() const{

cout << fixed << setprecision (1) << "[" << "(" << p1->getX()  <<", " << p1->getY() <<  ")" << "," << "(" << p2->getX() << ", " << p2->getY() << ")" << "]" ;

}
```

**Point.hpp**

```
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

class Point{

    private: // can only be used by public

        double x;
        double y;

    public:
    ///constructor
        Point (double X=0, double Y=0) : x(X), y(Y) {}

    //functions

        void setX(double x) {this->x= x ;}
        double getX() const {return this->x ;}

        void setY(double y) {this->y=y ;}
        double getY() const {return this->y ;}

        void print() const;

        friend bool operator== (Point lhp, Point rhp);
        friend bool operator> (Point lhp, Point rhp);
        friend bool operator< (Point lhp, Point rhp);

};


void Point::print() const{

    cout << "(" << this->x<< ","<<this->y<<")" << endl;


}


bool operator== (Point lhp, Point rhp){
    if((lhp.x == rhp.x && lhp.y == rhp.y)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}


bool operator> (Point lhp, Point rhp){

    int euclideanLeft, euclideanRight;

    euclideanLeft = sqrt((pow(lhp.x, 2))+(pow(lhp.y,2)));
    euclideanRight = sqrt((pow(rhp.x, 2))+(pow(rhp.y,2)));

    if((euclideanLeft > euclideanRight)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}


bool operator< (Point lhp, Point rhp){

   return !((lhp.x > rhp.x, lhp.y > rhp.y) || (lhp.x == rhp.x, lhp.y == rhp.y));

}

#endif
```

**lines.txt**

```
lines:
{
[line1:[102.0,0.9],[97.0,1.0]],
[line2:[103.0,0.8],[98.0,1.0]],
[line3:[104.0,0.7],[99.0,1.0]],
[line4:[105.0,0.6],[100.0,1.0]]
}
```

**lines_2.txt**

```
lines:
{
[line2:[103.0,0.8],[98.0,1.0]],
[line1:[102.0,0.9],[97.0,1.0]],
[line4:[105.0,0.6],[100.0,1.0]],
[line3:[104.0,0.7],[99.0,1.0]]
}
```

Comment: `Point* p1;  Point* p2;` -- Why are these pointers?  It looks like you created a problem when none had to exist.  Why aren't these simply `Point p1; Point p2;`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Looks like most of the code here is for testing. You should remove all that and focus in the issue. Read how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I am using the pointers to the class Point, because it is part of my assignment. Thank everyone for the feedback though. 

 "(a) Define private data members p1 and p2 as pointer to Point objects (the one we had in lectures), slope and length as double variables."

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the fact that there is no real reason why Line is keeping pointers to Points....

Your copy constructor is only doing a shallow copy which means you end up with multiple Line instances pointing to the same points:

```cpp
Line::Line(const Line& line){

    this->p1 = new Point ;
    this->p2 = new Point ;

    this->p1 = line.p1; // this overwrites the newly allocated
    this->p2 = line.p2; // p1 and p2 above. 

    length = line.length;
    slope = line.slope;

}
```

Should be something like:

```cpp
Line::Line(const Line& line){

    this->p1 = new Point(line.p1->getX(), line.p1->getY());
    this->p2 = new Point(line.p2->getX(), line.p2->getY());

    length = line.length;
    slope = line.slope;

}
```

If this is not for some class that requires the `Point`s in `Line` to be pointers I would really recommend you consider just storing the Points in the lines. It will solve a lot of headaches.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks a lot ^^. You literally saved my assignment. And yes, using pointers to the Point class is a requirement for my assignment. My professor wants us to get used to pointer syntax and so forth:  "(a) Define private data members p1 and p2 as pointer to Point objects (the one we had in lectures), slope and length as double variables."

Comment: @RobertCabrera One good way of saying "thanks" in SO is to  upvote and/or accept the answer.